# SOAP request in Java works locally but not on server

Tags: java, soap

I have a webapp that sends a SOAP request to a 3rd party server.  When the request is made on my local computer it works without a problem, but when I deploy my application to my server I get an error with the following causes:

com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: java.security.PrivilegedActionException: com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Message send failed

Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: algorithm check failed: MD2withRSA is disabled

I've searched around but I can't find anything relevant to my situation.  It's probably worth noting that the request I'm making is to an https url.  My computer is running Windows XP and the server is running Slackware Linux.  Any ideas what might be causing the server to reject the request?

Comment: How are you making your soap request? It would appear that the maybe the server is expecting a certain security certificate which you're not providing as part of your request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MD2withRSA is highly vulnerable and therefore deactivated in Sun... aeh Oracle's JVM. You should ask the owner of the remote service, whether his server supports more secure encryption methods (I think, older Apache HTTPd versions do offer MD2withRSA by default...). In order to resolve this problem without forcing the provider to change the method, you may use your own implementation of the X509TrustManager that accepts the old method.

Comment: This works, obviously not ideal but I'll get in contact with the owner of the service and see if there's anything else that can be done (I doubt I'll be able to get anything changed though, everything is antiquated).

Thank you!

Comment: If the owner does understand the implications of MD2 and collision attacks, he should not hesitate with changes. Event MD5 and SHA1 are vulnerable today.

Answer (score 2):

Check your Java versions on your local machine, and your server.
From [here](http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=5415963), it seems the jvm 6u17 disabled MD2 as it is insecure, and whatever you connect to is using MD2

Answer (score 1):

A Google search on "MD2withRSA" showed [this URL](http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=5415963) as the first hit, that seems to point to a change in a certain Java version. Probably the verasiuons on your local computer and the server do not match.

Comment: It's not a bug. It's a feature ;)

Comment: Reading that post in more detail shows it is a deactivation of an insecure method, but from a first view it seemed to me a bug in that version. I edited my answer, replacing "bug" by "change".

Answer (score 0):

Newer Java 7 (version 1.7) allows re-enabling MD2 via $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/**java.security** file. Download and install Java 7 and modify  java.security file in text editor as follows

1) Remove MD2 from following property
*jdk.certpath.disabledAlgorithms= # MD2*

2) Ensure following property is commented out
*# jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=MD5, SHA1, DSA, RSA keySize < 2048*

3) Restart java application

**Warning:** MD2 is disabled by default in Jdk 7 because it is insecure. However, it can be enabled as described above to support older deployments.