# Webservice fails as newline/spacing is added in SOAPMessage

Tags: java, web-services, soap

I am creating a SOAPMessage to be returned to the client over webservice.
During my localized testing(using TCPMon), I see this SOAPMessage as a response but it fails over the webservice.

I used Wireshark for a bit of diagnostics and found that this reponse xml(SOAPMessage) is corrupted as in it adds a line break at 1024th character. I do not know if the response is right formed and for some reason Wireshark adds the line break or this response gets genuinely corrupted. I am using Tomcat

To give an idea about how the code is strutured it is something like -

At some point in the flow I set the following(I removed these 2 lines but still the same result)

```
//httpservletResponse.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");
//httpservletResponse.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
```

Later in the flow, I do the following

```
try {
servletOS = httpservletResponse.getOutputStream();
soapMessage.writeTo(servletOS);
servletOS.close();
} finally {
    httpservletResponse.flushBuffer();
}
```

The above code is just to give a basic understanding, please consider that it compiles fine and all user defined values are properly set.
I am struggling to even narrow down where the exact problem might be, the actualy SOAPMessage due to its encoding etc? the stream being flushed/closed etc? client?

I would be glad to provide more information.

Please also note that a similar process using SAAJ works absolutely fine in the same environment.

This is how I build my response -

```
MessageFactory messageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
SOAPMessage soapMessage = messageFactory.createMessage();
SOAPPart responseSOAPPart = faultMessage.getSOAPPart();
SOAPEnvelope responseEnvelope = responseSOAPPart.getEnvelope();  
soapMessage.setProperty(SOAPMessage.CHARACTER_SET_ENCODING, "UTF-8");
soapMessage.setProperty(SOAPMessage.WRITE_XML_DECLARATION, "true");  
responseEnvelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("xsd", "http://........");
responseEnvelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("wsa", "http://......");
// and others  
SOAPHeader soapHeader = responseEnvelope.getHeader();  
// creating various SOAPHeaderElements viz. wsa:To,  wsa:Action, wsa:From etc. 
// and adding these to the SOAPHeader  
// Adding SOAPBody
SOAPBody body = soapMessage.getSOAPBody();
// add body element  
soapMessage.saveChanges()
```

Comment: why are you setting the content type of a SOAP response as "html"?  also, showing some code around how you actually create the response would be useful.

Comment: @jtahlborn Well I have removed the lines where I set the encoding and content type but no change on the output on Wireshark. I have edited my question with bit more code.

Comment: The linebreak could be TCP chunking, and might not be corrupting things at all

Comment: @artbristol Its entirely possible and thats what I dont know whether it is Wireshark that is adding the linebreak while displaying the response.

Comment: Try looking at it using 'Follow TCP Stream' instead of looking at the packet

Comment: @artbristol Thats what I do. 'Follow TCP stream' is what gives out the response with a line break.

Comment: OK, so how about looking at the packet itself?

Comment: have you tried writing the soap response to a file to confirm that you aren't adding the line break in your code?

Comment: @jtahlborn Yes. I did write this entire response to a file and its fine, the content and is a well formed xml.

Comment: instead of looking at the data low-level, you might try using an http proxy instead.  e.g. charles proxy is _very_ useful for debugging webservice interaction problems.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SOAP request in Java works locally but not on server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3587485/soap-request-in-java-works-locally-but-not-on-server)